# Using Ansible docker_service module to deploy service to swarm

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a Docker service into swarm but always ending up with running container on my localhost (the one I use as a docker swarm manager) and no service

Here's my setup:

I have 3 node Docker (v. 1.12.1) swarm that includes one host running as manager and two worker nodes all running on CentOS 7. On the manager node (localhost) I run Ansible (v. 2.1.1.0) playbook and the swarm is already configured and is running

```
Swarm: active
 NodeID: d9h5xa832ax7wzeq8q44fjld3
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 9cztoin3gy2ntbwehsmrkjuxi
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 10.25.190.209
```

Starting with a playbook that has this code

```
- hosts: localhost
  name: Run JMeter test
  vars_files:
    - user.config.yml
  vars:
    execute_tpcds_test : "{{ run_tpcds_test }}"    
  roles:
    - { role: run_jmeter, when: execute_tpcds_test is defined and execute_tpcds_test ==1 }
```

Which calls this role:

```
- name: Deploy tpcds_tpg service to swarm
  docker_service:
    project_name: tpcds-tpg
    definition:
      version: '2'
      services:
        run_tests: 
          image: 'pbench/tpcds_tpg'
          volumes: 
            - /opt/pbench/run_output/
          command: ./run_jmeter.sh "{{jmeter_output_dir}}" 
  register: output
- debug: var=output
```

When I run `ansible-playbook ./site.yml` I end up with a running container. Doing `docker ps -a` displays

```
[pdo@sdl02133 tpcds-tpg]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fef245b41365        pbench/tpcds_tpg   "./run_jmeter.sh /opt"   21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds                           tpcdstpg_run_tests_1
```

And doing `docker service ls` shows no services running so it looks like `docker_service` deploys my image as a local container and not as a service on the swarm

So my assumption was that if I have an active swarm on the machine that is a swarm manager and I use Ansible `docker_service` module, then it will automatically be aware of the swarm and deploy the service to it. Looks like my assumption is wrong and I cannot find any docs, blog posts, etc. that would hint me what to do and what I am missing. Ansible experts please help!

Comment: I would expect a 7+ years user of StackExchange to know that [crossposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925167/using-ansible-docker-service-module-to-deploy-service-to-swarm) is discouraged.

Comment: @techraf you are right, dutifully noted and to my defence this is first time I'm doing this because I hate to admit but I'm desperate for answer. Unfortunately I placed the bounty on the Stackoverflow question that I hate to vaste. Would you suggest me to delete this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally. Basically my assumption in the last paragraph is false. At least for now. Turns out ansible's docker_service is just a wrapper around docker compose and that (very unfortunately) at the time of writing is not integrated with the docker swarm. Basically I'm out of luck here according to [this support thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3656)
The same thread [gives a possible workaround](https://github.com/ddrozdov/docker-compose-swarm-mode) if you are interested